# Import data from an e-mail account (Android Studio)

Tags: android, email

I am creating an app for android device and I was wondering if it is possible to connect my app with an e-mail account and have notifications every time the (let's say the gmail account) receives a new mail, and display the message in a new activity. I have researched a lot but I have not found something really useful.

Can anyone give me a clue on how to do it or even where to look for?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible. You have to create an email client.
[Here are some good email clients](http://www.androidauthority.com/best-android-email-apps-579368/)

You need to use the email client API for that. [Here is Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/gmail/v1?hl=en), you can find more my googling.